# why does negating a bind value in knockoutjs have to be unwrapped

Tags: knockout.js

I've noticed that in KnockoutJS that value binding doesn't work if it is negated:

like so:

```
data-bind="showTip: enableTip, css: { disabled: !addButtonEnabled }"
```

doesn't correctly pickup the negated addButtonEnabled variable.

However, this does work:

```
data-bind="showTip: enableTip, css: { disabled: !addButtonEnabled() }"
```

Why is it that this has to be unwrapped, where the other doesn't?

I'm using knockout 1.2.1.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Let me explain a bit how KO parse bindings in your example.

In fact data-bind contains JSON. KO wraps it with {} symbols and evaluate as normal JS code.
In your example KO got this object after evaluation:

```
{
    showTip: enableTip,
    css: { disabled: !addButtonEnabled }
}
```

`css` bindingHandler receives node binding should be applied to and bindingAccessor function.

After evaluation of this function we get an "argument" for `css` binding. which is equal to object

```
{ disabled: !addButtonEnabled }
```

Then `css` bindingHandler iterates through properties of this object to set corresponding styles. When it comes to `disabled` property we need to read value for it.

Usually all standard bindings read value in this way: `ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value)` which returns `value` if `value` is not observable or value stored in this observable variable.

In your case `value = !addButtonEnabled`. As you can see `!addButtonEnabled` is JavaScript expression, not observable. So it just evaluates this expression. So in fact your button is always enabled since `observable() != false`.

In your second case value to be evaluated contains value of observable so it works correct.

I think you

Comment: I know this is old, but I was searching this because `disabled: observable1 || observable2` doesn't need either of those observables unwrapped, but I would expect they should for the same reason you gave in your answer - the binding is to a javascript expression, not simply an observable.